# Pixel 4 Motion Sense Support

Tags: android, google-pixel

How do I get Pixel 4's Motion Sense to work with my music apps? Google's (of course) works. So does Spotify's.

The Pixel 4 support team clearly states that 3rd party devs are the issue, and we should visit https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion which doesn't seem to have Motion Sense documentation.

I've filed a bug with Google as well.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143434555

Comment: Where is the response from the support team that blames the developers?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I went through the support app on the Pixel 4, and support told me that the issue is that the dev hasn't implemented this feature. Try it. They won't hesitate to blame developers since it works with YouTube music.

Comment: Maybe the link they gave you will soon be updated to include Motion Sense. Not all APIs become public straight away. I'd be interested to see how it works myself, although they may not necessarily think there's a reason to release it just yet, considering there are only a handful of devices that support it currently